# How do you implement an API.AI bot in python?

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I have an agent created in dialogflow. i want to know if there is any way that we can send request through python and get the response from dialogflow agent. 
I have got way for the same with .net. where we access it through clientAccessToken.

```
 var config = new AIConfiguration(ACCESS_TOKEN, SupportedLanguage.English);
 apiAi = new ApiAi(config);
```

The above code is in c#.
Is there any way through which I can do the same in python??

Comment: There is a Python client for Dialogflow https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-python-client-v2

Comment: what is project id, session id that is given as parameter in the function?

Comment: I am sorry I haven't worked on Python client yet. I just notified you that there is a Python client.

Comment: ohh ok... thanks :)